# React - useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So i have a simple to-do app, click here to [Link removed].

The problem i have is that in Console > Network i get too many same `GET` requests so it looks like
i have an infinite loop. Im probably not coding this right in useEffect, since the effect triggers my http get methods which contain setTodos(data) which makes it trigger useEffect again.

What im trying to achieve is the same functionality that the web app has right in this moment, but with appropriate coding:

- Fetching the appropriate data every time user clicks some category.
- I also want to trigger fetch for specific category each time user either adds/edits/deletes a 'todo' so i can achieve 'live feed'.

EDIT : What i tried right now is implementing `useState [test,setTest]`. I added `setTest(!test)` to my funcs: `addTodo`, `removeTodo`, `markTodo` and to my `category btn onClick` func. I also put `[test]` to dep. array in my useEffect. Sometimes list updates correctly, sometimes it doesnt at all, and sometimes it udpates but incorrectly (ex: when i mark a todo, it gets marked/crossed and then it gets unmarked 1sec after. But if i refresh the page its ok).

useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(filter === 'Completed')
    httpRequestHandler(`${baseAPIurl}/completed`, "GET");
  
  else if(filter === 'Active')
    httpRequestHandler(`${baseAPIurl}/notcompleted`, "GET");

  else
    httpRequestHandler(`${baseAPIurl}/todos`, "GET");

});
```

And here is part of my httpRequestHandler function

```
const httpRequestHandler = async (url, type, data) =>
  {
      let request = {}
        
        if(type === 'GET')
        {
            request = {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"} 
            };

            await fetch(url, request)
                    .then((response)=> {
                      return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((data)=> {
                        setTodos(data);
                    });

            return;
        }
...........................

}
```

Comment: Did you try providing `todos` or `setTodos` inside the dependency array? It's hard to see what exactly you are trying to do from the provided code here.

Comment: @debaM I have `setTodos` in my `httpHandler` func. So it will be an infinite loop. Check out my EDIT in original post to see what i've tried out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of your code, you need to adjust the dependency array

more info, eg. [here](https://dennyscott.io/use-effect-dependency-array/#what-is-the-dependency-array)

Comment: I tried using dependency array but while using that i couldnt achieve my list to update every time someone makes a change to it. Will try again. Note: without categories menu i would achieve this easily.

Comment: its hard to see the big picture from provided code. what is happening now: useEffect is a) called on every render, and b) causes a new render. hence the loop. you'll need to reorganize the code, so that you can use the dependency array to prevent (a).

Comment: What i tried right now is implementing `useState [test,setTest]`. I added `setTest(!test)` to my funcs: `addTodo`, `removeTodo`, `markTodo` and to my category btn `onClick` func. I also put `[test]` to dep. array in my` useEffect`. I still dont get my list updated everytime i add/remove/edit a todo. Sometimes funcs work and list renders correctly, sometimes list doesnt render, some times list renders incorrectly (ex: when i mark a todo it gets marked and then unmarked again but if i refresh the page everything is how it is supposed to be). No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `filter` into dependency array to only update on filter change?

```
useEffect(() => { ... }, [filter])
```

Comment: I actually think i did, but then again, i need useEffect triggered when i add/edit/delete a todo. Those funcs do not contain setFilter, therefor they do not trigger useEffect. Check my EDIT in post.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what was causing my useEffect not to trigger in the first place, i already tried this but now it works (no idea why). What i did is:

- Implemented `useState [trigger, setTrigger]`
- In my `httpHandler` func (which handles http requests), specifically in PUT/DELETE/POST part of the func where i use fetch(--, --) i added `setTrigger(!trigger)` to `.then()` part.
- Added `[trigger]` to useEffect dependency array